# bootstrap responsive not working inside angular directive template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and angular directives.
My angular directive template uses bootstraps class 'col-md-3' and initial rendering it works. But on page resize, my directive which renders html content is not responsive (not rearranging contents based on window size).

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <my-dir data-list="arrayOfObjects">
     <my-card item="card"></mycard>
  </my-dir>
</div>

my-dir is my first directive, which uses ng-repeat like below
<div class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="card in dataList">
   <div inject></div>
</div>
inject is another of my directive which has code like below
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, controller, $transclude) {
    var innerScope = $scope.$new();
    $transclude(innerScope, function(clone) {
      $element.empty();
      $element.append(clone);
      $element.on('$destroy', function() {
        innerScope.$destroy();
      });
    });
  }
```

Why is bootstrap failing to work .. if instead of using directives, i directly put my code using "col-md-3" then it works.

Comment: can you try replace:'true' in the directive?

Comment: replace: true did not help ...

Comment: created a plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/PGhHPXKk51zlVx1V2deQ?p=preview)  , In the plunker, i have commented out regular div's which resize properly, but the divs created by transclusion/ng-repeat etc does not resize properly.

Comment: @NagaSandeep You know what bro, You are a life savior, you saved my life with replace:true. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had the same issue and realized that the `replace: true` only works if you have a template. Once I put the template in there, it worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37639446/4960108
you might want to try this one.